# A good Report Design tool/Library

Tags: reporting, report-designer

I have to produce multiple reports on a regular basis; same reports are produced for the whole customer base.
My problem is that designing the layout of the reports is long and tedious job.

What I need is a GUI tool for designing the layout of the reports.

The output of the tool should be xsl file that will used for creating reports in batch. Additional option is that the toll will provide a library that will allow build a customized batch process for report creation based on GUI layout definitions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for an open source tool give BIRT (http://www.eclipse.org/birt/) a try.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you are using reports in HTML form from XML data, right?
If is not "XSL file" condition for reporting, try some reporting tool. They has designer, exports to pdf/html/doc/etc..., someones also end-user-designer and much more.

[My response for similar question: Crystal Reports .Net Guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116324/crystal-reports-net-guidance/116371#116371)

Answer (score 0):

We (the company I work for) produce a tool called [RSinteract](http://www.rsinteract.com). I don't know if it's exactly what you're looking for since you have not specified the data source you're reporting on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to an XSL [Altova's Stylevision product](http://www.altova.com/products/stylevision/xslt_stylesheet_designer.html). If you're interested in looking at a third party tool that saves reports in another XML dialect look at our products at http://www.datadynamics.com

```
Scott Willeke
Data Dynamics / GrapeCity
```